# URL decode and encode in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm slightly confused on how to use the URL decode and encode in PHP and I need some clarification on this please.

Basically, I have a MYSQL data that has single quotes in it like this:

```
This is the third\&#39;s title that goes here!!
```

The `&#39;` is the HTML code for single quote.

Now I use that in the URL like so:

```
title.php?t=This is the third's title that goes here!!
```

And in my PHP code I try to use it like so:

```
$title = $_GET['t'];

$urlsafe_title = urlencode($title);
$url = $urlsafe_title;
$htmlsafe_url = htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5);


$title = utf8_decode(urldecode($htmlsafe_url));
```

But when I try to use that variable $title to search in the MYSQL database, I get no result at all. But when I remove the single quote from both title and MYSQL database, everything works fine.

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should make use of URL slugs, that is input like "Hello World" can be sent as "hello-world". So here's a function that can help you out:

```
function gen_slug($url)
{
    //prepare string with basic normalization
    $url = strtolower($url);
    $url = strip_tags($url);
    $url = stripslashes($url);
    $url = html_entity_decode($url);
    //Remove any quotes
    $url = str_replace('\"','',$url);
    //Replace non-alpha chars with '-'
    $match = '/[^a-z0-9]+/';
    $replace = '-';
    $url = preg_replace($match, $replace, $url);
    $url = trim($url, '-');
    return $url;
}
```

You will have to create an extra column on your table like `title-slug` or something like that, so you could use it as a reference.

So in your case, it could be like this: `title.php?t=this-is-my-title`

Hope it helps you! :)